# How do I pass an Id into JavaScript (getElementByID) if the id in my input tag is generated by php/mysql output?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, getelementbyid

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am trying to search through all the id's in the following to see if the data has been selected by the user.

```
<input id=\"".$row['childName']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"foodData[]\"  value=\""$row['foodCalories']"\"><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id=\"".$row['careHome']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"lifestyle\"  value=\"".$row['sportActivities']."\"\>this should be checked too.. </label>

<script> function lastResort(){
    var x = document.getElementById(\"".$row['childName']."\).value; \\this is unrecognised

    var y = document.getElementById(\"".$row['careHome']."\"); \\ unrecognised

    (... function to checkboxes..) <-- this part works
} </script>;
```

I also found that if I compromise and leave the id the same (like the `word = \"eat\"`) for all the values, it only runs the function for the first row of results.

Comment: `script` tag is invalid, it should look like `<script> /*your code*/ </script>`

Comment: Thanks Barbsan. Editing that now. It must have gotten muddled up when I was transfering it to SO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest you don't output in strings. Try to use a simple view method for rendering things. It makes it easier for you to edit the HTML and prevents all the errors of unquoted characters etc.. what you can get.

```
class Controller 
{
    public function makePartial($file, $vars = []) 
    {
        extract($vars);
        ob_start();
           include($file);
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
    }
    public function render() 
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Then in your view you'd have something like this

view.html

```
<input id="<?= $row['childName'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="<?= $row['foodCalories'] ?>"\><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="<?= $row['careHome'] ?>" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="<?= $row['sportActivities'] ?>"\>this should be checked too.. </label>

<script>
    function lastResort(){
        var x = document.getElementById("<?= $row['childName']?> ").value; \\this is unrecognised

    var y = document.getElementById("<?= $row['careHome']?>").value; \\ unrecognised

    (... function to checkboxes..) <-- this part works
};
</script>
```

Which you can render by extending the controller

```
class foodController extends Controller 
{
    protected function getRows() 
    {
       // magic to get rows
       return $rows;
    }
    public function render() 
    {
       $output = [];
       $rows = $this->getRows();
       foreach($rows as $row) {
          $output[] = $this->makePartial('view.html', ['row' => $row]);
       }
       return implode('', $output);
    }
}
```

Which would end up with an output like

```html
<input id="childName" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="250"/><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="careHome" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="discus"/>this should be checked too.. </label>
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
<script>
    function lastResort(){
        var x = document.getElementById("childName").value; //this is unrecognised

        var y = document.getElementById("careHome").value; //unrecognised
        console.log(x, y);
    };
    document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', lastResort);
</script>
```

By seperating the renderflow to the individual id's, or storing them in a seperate array you can accomplish what you want.

I'd advice storing the id's in a seperate array and rendering the javascript in a seperate view.

row.html

```
<input id="<?= $childName ?>" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="<?= $foodCalories ?>"\><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="<?= $careHome ?>" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="<?= $sportActivities ?>"\>this should be checked too.. </label>
```

javascript.html

```
<script>
    function lastResort(){
         <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
             if(document.getElementById('<?=$row['childName']?>').checked) {
                   document.getElementById('<?=$row['careHome']?>').checked = true;
             }
             else {
                   document.getElementById('<?=$row['careHome']?>').checked = false;
             }
         <?php endforeach; ?>
    }
};
</script>
```

Which you can render with

```
class foodController extends Controller 
{
    protected function getRows() 
    {
       // magic to get rows
       return $rows;
    }
    public function render() 
    {
       $output = [];
       $rows = $this->getRows();
       foreach($rows as $row) {
          $output[] = $this->makePartial('row.html', $row);
       }
       $output[] = $this->makePartial('javascript.html', $rows);
       return implode('', $output);
    }
}
```

Which would give an output like

```html
<input id="childName1" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="250"/><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="careHome1" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="discus"/>this should be checked too.. </label>
<BR/>
<input id="childName2" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="250"/><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="careHome2" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="discus"/>this should be checked too.. </label>
<BR/>
<input id="childName3" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="250"/><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="careHome3" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="discus"/>this should be checked too.. </label>
<BR/>
<input id="childName4" type="checkbox" name="foodData[]"  value="250"/><label> If this is selected </label>

<label><input id="careHome4" type="checkbox" name="lifestyle"  value="discus"/>this should be checked too.. </label>
<BR/>
<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
<script>
    function lastResort(){
        if(document.getElementById('childName1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('careHome1').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('careHome1').checked = false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('childName2').checked) {
            document.getElementById('careHome2').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('careHome2').checked = false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('childName3').checked) {
            document.getElementById('careHome3').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('careHome3').checked = false;
        }
        if(document.getElementById('childName4').checked) {
            document.getElementById('careHome4').checked = true;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('careHome4').checked = false;
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', lastResort);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tschallacka! I see what you mean by not outputting in strings. But not as clear on the rendering part. Is this done in HTML/ JavaScript? Sorry if that's a very basic question. I'm still new to this. Thanks again!

Comment: @BelleDeveloper Basically what the render code does is "extracting" the array so the array keys become the variable names. Then in does a basic php include, which means any php code in the file will get executed too with access to the php vari ables. By using the short echo `<?= 'boo' ?>` you can easely echo out the variables. It will be as if you defined the variables at the top of your file, but you just defined them in the controller in the array you passed to the makePartial method.